# Asp.net Web Api. Post a complex model to Controller and received model incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with Post a complex model object from client to Web Api controller.
My model structure is:

```
public class PaymentModel
{
    public Credit Crediter { get; set; }
}

public class Credit : ICredit
{
    public int BankInformationId { get; set; }
}

public interface ICredit
{
    int BankInformationId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CrediterEmployee:Credit
{
    public int EnployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to create a model to post to API controller:

```
var param = new PaymentModel
{
    Crediter = new CrediterEmployee
    {
        BankInformationId = 4928,
        EnployeeId = 7013
    },
}
```

In API controller I received a model object, but for `Crediter` I cannot cast to `CreditEmployee`. It is `null` when I tried to cast.

How can I cast `Crediter` to the `CreditEmployee`?

Comment: Are you using the default model binder? If so try to create a custom one for your complex model.

Comment: inspect the request, and see if the sent form data or json from the client is in line with your strongly typed class `PaymentModel`

Comment: I can have the model object but problem is i cannot cast Crediter to EmployeeCrediter

Comment: so are you saying, in the model received, you have a valid value for `param.Crediter.BankInformationId`, before you typecast ?

Comment: Actually, the problem i think that looks like the model binder for interface.

Comment: then you should do it with your custom model binder

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? ... And have you tried to do the POST maybe with tool like POSTMAN? (to be sure you're not sending an empty body)

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Credit))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] PaymentModel payment)
        {
            try
            {
                if (payment == null || payment.Crediter == null) return BadRequest();
                var response = new Credit
                {
                    BankInformationId = payment.Crediter.BankInformationId
                };

                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The default binder cannot handle in this case, your answer is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean to use ... something like

Comment: Do you mean to use ... something like    var resp = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var payment = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentModel>(resp);